# How Does ASP.NET associate a request with a session?

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there a cookie automatically placed on the user's machine?  Or is it somehow associated with the requester's IP address?  Or maybe in the ViewState?  Elementary question, I know, but I've had a hard time finding an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IIS, under ASP.NET's configuration there is a State Management Tab which has a setting called "Cookieless mode" which has the options of:

UseUri

UseCookies

AutoDetect

UseDeviceProfile

Typically, "Use Cookies" is selected and thus a cookie is used.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `ASP.NET_SessionId`.

For a local app, mine's currently

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=kxt1dee1laeuq445pyzjvv55; path=/; domain=localhost; HttpOnly
```

You can make it use URLs, but it gets messy really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cookie

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MSDN Overview article that describes the process and what options you have:

[**ASP.NET Session State Overview**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

In particular, note at the bottom that if your user's authenticate to access your site, you should do an Abandon of the session upon logout so that session states don't persist.